# how to edit and change/rename the title(React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

Hello:) I am writing simple application(similar to to-do-list). The task is to add such functionality as the ability to change the title of the announcement.

1. You add the title and description of the announcement and click on "submit" button -> https://prnt.sc/tf8zxl
2. the annoncement appears below and you need to have the ability to change the title of it(rename it)->https://prnt.sc/tf8xa2

I added the input when click on the title but it does not allow to write inside it and I do not have any ideas on how to save it in this.state.data correctly.

here is the source code -> https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-darkness-uh9xl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: the issue with title change is resolved but it is causing the issue with the delete option. It does not delete the correct item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Controlled input

If you need controlled input you have to change values somehow. You are not changing anything at this moment and you are calling `handleChange` which changes `state.title`, not `state.data[someIndex].title` - so the value cannot be changed.

I've provided [modified solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-jepsen-7l8i7?file=/src/App.js) where is updating finnished.

---

#### Uncontrolled input

If you are OK with uncontrolled input you are probably looking for `input` attribute `defaultValue` instead of `value`. It doesn't change because you are not changing `value` at all so it's being instantly re-rendered with original value from `this.props.data.title`.

I've set value by attribute `defaultValue` and changed `onChange` on `onBlur` so update will triger only when you lose focus.
Your [modified codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-rgb-qwoo9?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: thank youuuu :) I was trying to deal with it from yesterday

Comment: I noticed that the delete option works incorrectly then.

Comment: @MartaKozak I just aimed at the problem _how to edit and change_ and I didn't target your problems with callback methods which are updating the state. There are more problems and pretty nonsense parts of code. You are probably looking for something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-jepsen-7l8i7?file=/src/App.js) (updated original answer with 2 variants). I hope it will help you to better understand whats going on.

Comment: Yes, I see now. I have checked the code and It helps me a lot. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Use input in this way

```
const [title,setTitle] = useState('')

<input type="text" value={title} onChange={(e)=>setTitle(e.target.value)} />
```